# Any tricks anyone can recommend on how to uniquely identify a window (in any app) after restart?

Tags: applescript, windows

I have a fun little project I am working on.  I am developing an AppleScript that saves and restores windows to their original desktops (a.k.a. "Spaces") after a restart or an app relaunch.  The script actually is working very well and largely succeeds in restoring assigned desktop positions (though I have not yet optimized it for speed).

There are only a few apps that macOS doesn't automatically restore to their original desktops after a restart (e.g. Stickies), but quitting and re-launching an app (i.e. no restart involved) always dumps all windows on the current desktop.

One problem with my script is that I have not found an ideal solution to, is how to uniquely identify all windows.  Window attributes accessed via "System Events" do not have a unique id.  (Individual app's window objects *do* have a unique window ID, but those IDs do not survive a restart unchanged.)  **Window names are sufficient for most document type windows** *(E.g. TextEdit)* and single window apps usually have one unchanging window name *(with some exceptions (e.g. Slack))*, but they do not work for windows of apps like Safari *(named by current web page)*, Terminal *(naming options do not include unique persistent identifiers - even the tty option changes after restart)*, and Finder *(named by current folder)*.

When I run my script, after a restart, random Terminal windows will swap desktops and if I didn't save the positions right before an app relaunch, some Safari windows will not be moved (because their names changed, since it's no longer at the same web address).

Some individual apps have their own custom means of editing window names (e.g. Terminal has `echo -n -e "\033]0;Custom Name Here\007"`), which I could add custom code to handle, but I'm looking for a universal solution that works on any app.

I have an idea for a work-around, but it has side-effects.  It's based on the following: If I use each window's AXPosition, AXSize, and or AXFrame values to use as a sort of "unique window signature", I can narrow down some window identities, though often times, windows tend to auto-open in the same relative position/size/frame on different desktops (these values are all relative to the desktop they're on, so windows in the same relative position/size/frame on different desktops hence have the same position/size/frame and they cannot be differentiated using those values).  However, these values are mutable, so when I save the desktop positions, I can tweak their size or position to make them uniquely identifiable across all desktops using those characteristics.  Another drawback is that those values become useless if the user manually moves or resizes a window.

I've been exploring window attributes via "System Events", looking for an unused value where I could save some sort of ID that would persist through a restart, but other than position/size/frame, nothing else appears to be settable.  Does anyone know a trick to set arbitrary window attributes?

One idea I had to mitigate the identification problem is to assume that if windows of an app are already on more than 1 desktop, I can assume they do not need to be rearranged.  That would both make the script faster and address spurious window movements such as is the case with the Terminal app.

*Incidentally, I suspect people will be curious how I am able to move windows across desktops via AppleScript and that I've been coy about revealing that, but I will be posting the code on github when I'm done.*

Comment: You can see all properties with a command like ` tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Pages" to get properties of window 1`—but that won't help you. I think your best bet would be to look into how macOS natively stores restorable windows—`~/Library/Saved Application State`.